# What’s the purpose of the small “hole” in front of wing root on A320-214?

Tags: wing, airbus-a320, feature-identification, airbus-neo

[image]

Someone knows what’s the purpose of this little “hole”?

Comment: There is a bit of dirt, but not a heat shield.  This means it's an exhaust port for something, but not something super hot, like combustion air (like an APU, which would be a lot bigger anyway).  It's likely an exhaust for a heat exchanger of some kind, possibly a hydraulic fluid cooler (an air conditioning heat exchanger outlet would be larger).

Comment: Are you sure it's an A320neo? Other pictures of the plane showing the right side (such as [here](https://www.aviation24.be/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Lufthansa-Airbus-A320neo.jpg) and [here](https://assets.bwbx.io/images/users/iqjWHBFdfxIU/iOG0T5xomEfc/v1/1000x-1.jpg) and [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Wataniya_Airways_A320-200_9K-EAA_DXB_2009-1-23.png)) don't show such a feature.

Comment: Are you sure that's a picture of an A320NEO?

Comment: CUT HERE IN EMERGENCY...pure plane, please don't cut it!

Comment: Did you take that picture? If so, can you tell us which airline this was and from where to where you were flying. That should help narrow down the actual aircraft. If it's not your picture, could you add the source to the question? A reverse Google image search did not find anything.

Comment: Pretty sure it is an A320 like this one. The Portuguese helped me narrow it down.   https://www.jetphotos.com/photo/8795441

Comment: Here is another one. Whatever it is it's not standard: Most 214s don't have one.
 https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Airbus_A320-214,_TAP_Portugal_JP6867739.jpg

Comment: I’m sorry for delaying in replying! So, I’m not sure if aircraft is an A320NEO. The aircraft tail number is PR-TYN an A320-214. I think that this “hole” is connected to (Inert Gas System), but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 8):

My company's A320 also have that mystery hole. After a thorough search, it's the vent outlet hole for dumping the forward cargo compt air overboard, through the extraction fan (6HN) and outlet isolation valve (4HN). Detail can be found in cargo ventilation chapter (ATA 21-28-00).

It seems that hole are not installed on every A320. From the SRM (Structural Repair Manual), that hole is surrounded by a doubler and the doubler can only be found on ...... 282 aircraft (data as of today).

Comment: SRM = Structural Repair Manual? Can you add it in the answer?

Comment: @ROIMaison Yes and added, I thought it was quite a well-known acronym

Answer (score 2):

It leads to a vent in the cargo compartment that Airbus calls "Outlet-Extraction". It must be an option that isn't installed very often.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Do you have any references to support your answer? We appreciate that kind of thing.